# Placing multiple instances of same control on form

Tags: c#, winforms

I am making an application in winforms which shows a blueprint in a picturebox, and I need to place parts on it programmatically. These parts needs to be clickable (thus they should be a user control), and then fire the corresponding click event (clicking on a part should display information unique to that part). I could say that I want to place custom buttons on my picture. Now, of course, I need only one click event, and change the displayed information according to selection, though I don't know how to "link" this event to each created button.

I have a list of parts right next to the picturebox, and selecting a part should make the associated control to appear on the form (and deselecting it should remove it, or at least make it hidden). At first, I thought I will create one control during design, and make it appear/disappear and relocate it with each selection. The problem is, that the user should be able to select multiple parts, and the program should show all selected parts on the blueprint.

As each blueprint is different, the number of parts cannot be defined in advance. Is it possible, to create multiple instances of the same control on the run? Or is there a workaround?

Comment: And the usual questions follow. What have you tried? Where is the code already written? Where are you stuck?

Comment: If you want to "link" the `click` event to button you can simply double click on it (**not** in running time) and your focus will navigate to its `click` event

Comment: @Steve: And the usual answer: I have tried nothing in this particular problem, because I don't know how. Supplying other parts of the code won't help you understand my problem. If you couldn't understand it, tell me what information are you missing, and I will edit it, but a code won't help you or me any further. As of the question, where am I stuck, is already written down. Please read it carefully next time.

Comment: @Eli I know that ;) Please read my problem, it is entirely different.

Comment: Just as a small note to you, controls in winforms aren't ever fully disposed until the form has been closed

Comment: Sure they are, @Sayse. They are disposed as soon as you call their `Dispose` method. Which you must do manually if you manually add/remove controls at run-time.

Comment: @CodyGray - Im sure I read on msdn somewhere that until the form has been disposed, references to the controls (including disposed) are retained. Of course, now I can't seem to find that quote..

Comment: Yes, child controls that are created automatically by the framework (e.g., those which you added in the designer). They're initialized in the `InitializeComponent` method added by the designer, and automatically destroyed when the container control is destroyed. This is not the case with controls that you add manually at runtime. You are responsible for managing their lifetimes yourself. Which, since they implement `IDisposable`, includes calling `Dispose`. @sayse

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use controls for your picture elements( you do not determine anything from coordinates of mouse click) and each picture element is associated with only one menu control, then I can propose you to use the [Tag](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.tag(v=vs.110).aspx) property to associate the corresponding menu controls:

```
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        this.CreatePictureRelatedControls();
    }

    private void CreatePictureRelatedControls()
    {
        Int32 xPictureControls = 50,
            yPictureControls = 50,
            xAssociatedControls = 200,
            yAssociatedControls = 50,
            yMargin = 10;

        Int32 controlWidth = 125,
            controlHeight = 20;


        Int32 controlCount = 3;

        // ---------Associated controls-----------------

        var associatedControls = new Button[controlCount];

        // Loop - creating associated controls
        for (int i = 0; i < associatedControls.Length; i++)
        {
            var associatedButton = new Button()
            {
                Left = xAssociatedControls,
                Top = yAssociatedControls + (i * (controlWidth + yMargin)),
                Width = controlWidth,
                Height = controlHeight,
                Text = String.Format("associated control {0}", i),
                Visible = false
            };

            // Event handler for associated button
            associatedButton.Click += (sender, eventArgs) =>
                {
                    MessageBox.Show(((Control)sender).Text, "Associated control clicked");
                };

            associatedControls[i] = associatedButton;
        }

        // ----------------- Picture controls ---------------
        var pictureControls = new Button[controlCount];

        // Loop - creating picture controls
        for (int i = 0; i < pictureControls.Length; i++)
        {
            var pictureButton = new Button()
            {
                Left = xPictureControls,
                Top = yPictureControls + (i * (controlWidth + yMargin)),
                Width = controlWidth,
                Height = controlHeight,
                Text = String.Format("picture part button {0}", i),
                // Use of tag property to associate the controls
                Tag = associatedControls[i],
                Visible = true
            };

            // Event hadler for picture button
            pictureButton.Click += (sender, eventArgs) =>
                {
                    Control senderControl = (Control)sender;
                    Control associatedControl = (Control)senderControl.Tag;

                    associatedControl.Visible = !associatedControl.Visible;
                };

            pictureControls[i] = pictureButton;
        }


        this.Controls.AddRange(associatedControls);
        this.Controls.AddRange(pictureControls);
    }
```

**P.S.** If you need to associate multiple controls then you can just set Tag property to some collection:

```
button.Tag = new Control[] {associated[1], associated[3]};
```